# How to program a hotfolder that sends files to a server like Dropbox does?

Tags: swift, dropbox, hotfolder

On a Mac I want to be able to setup a folder to automatically send files to a server when placed into it. Actually a very similar concept as Dropbox or Google Drive. I couldn't find any good resources that showed how to afford this.
Can anyone give me a hint or tell me how I couldn't build something like that on a Mac?

Comment: Basically it's a folder action (GUI level) which can be accomplished with `DispatchSourceFileSystemObject` to monitor the folder

Comment: Thank you! Do you know any good resources?